# Can BillingClient's queryPurchases give me a reliable statement about the ownership of an in app purchase?

Tags: android

i offer 1 in app purchase (full functionality). I save the result of the purchase in a boolean variable in sharedpreference and also use queryPurchases on app start, so if someone deleted and reinstalled the app, he gets his full functionality back.

That works properly, but i also would like to block full functionality, if it turns out, that someone did NOT purchase the full functionality (and cheated the app with a rooted device). That would also include deleting some data that he is not supposed to have without the in app purchase.

However, i am confused about the description of queryPurchases. It says

"Upon a successful purchase, Google Play's In-app Billing service caches the user's purchase data locally."

How long does it store that information? Does it update it automatically if an internet connection is available? How can i avoid getting no purchase even though the user bought the in app purchase and falsely blocking his full functionality? What is there

Is there a way to get the clear information, that the user in fact did NOT purchase a certain item, rather than just no information about a possible purchase? I really want to avoid blocking features if the user paid.

Anything else wrong with my approach (Saving the purchase in sharedpreferences 
to have the information available immediatly and additionaly query purchase)

Edit: I also noticed, that if i refund an in app purchase, de- and reinstall the app, queryPurchases still finds that purchase. There must a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother storing purchases in shared preferences. They are already on the device via the billing library. The purchases are stored in the Play store data which the billing library retrieves for you.

You can work by assuming that full functionality is enabled until you receive the result of query purchases which will tell you definitively whether the user has bought it or not. If you prefer, you can do that backwards and assume trial mode until you know a purchase exists.

Either way, the query for purchases will return quickly as no network connection is required because billing library simply connects to play store on the device for the data.

If you refund in the developer console, it may take a while for that to filter to the users device but it will eventually. It isn't a real time system and a purchase will remain cached on the device until the refund is fully processed and sent to the users device.

You can consume a purchase directly on a device which removes it instantly from the user account.

Comment: Thank you very much! And is that really reliable? Caching sounds like it wont be stored there forever. What if the user has no internet for a while, will the purchase information be removed eventually?

Comment: No all purchases made via play store are cached permanently on the device until you consume them or refund them.

Comment: So if queryPurchases is over and the purchase was not found, i can safely assume that it was never purchased and block full functionality? I wanna block it, rather than just unblock it on, to reverse changes someone made on a rooted device.

Comment: And if someone wipes his phone, will the purchase flag be recovered once he connects to google play?

Comment: Yes play store will download all purchases again after a factory reset or even if you clear the play store data from the app settings.

Comment: Thank you, you have been an IMMENSE help!